# Firefox bookmark recover

Tags: firefox-profile

So I completely reformatted my pc and reinstalled windows 10 and forgot to backup my profile. I do not have a winows.old because I formatted. Is there anyway to recover this or am I completely screwed?

Comment: Only at to determine if file recovery is possible is to try to recover the files but your actions typically mean your files are gone.  In the future keep better backups.

Comment: Plus, Firefox has it's own sync feature that can be used when reinstalling the whole OS or to sync between several PCs and other devices. The only caveat is you have to trust Mozilla with your "personal data" (bookmarks, browser settings and browsing history).

Answer (score 0):

Besides attempting file recovery (unlikely since you already wrote data to the same drive), your only chance of recovery is if you used Firefox's Sync functionality to backup all your bookmarks.

If you did that, you can use the same credentials to sync those bookmarks to a new Firefox installation.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes. Mozilla introduced a new iteration of Firefox Sync in Firefox 29, which was released in 2014. Even before that, Firefox had sync functionality, but it wasn't as polished as it became in 2014.